# What is the grade and source of this narration about eating with the right hand?

Tags: source-identification

> When the Prophet (Sallallahu Alaihi wa Sallam) saw a man eating with his left hand he said to him: "Eat with your right hand". The man said: 'I can't'. The Prophet (Sallallahu Alaihi wa Sallam) there upon said: "May you not be able". He refused (to eat with his right hand) out of arrogance only. He was not able to raise that hand again" .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hadith is considered as authentic as it is in sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/36/142) and the person cursed here is known as Busr ibn Ra'iy al-'ir al-Ashja'iy  بُسْر ابن راعي العير الأشجعي (also Bushr  بشر was quoted) some scholars like [ibn Manda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Manda) ابن مندة, [abu Nu'aym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Nu%60aym) أبو نعيم and  ibn Makula [ابن ماكولا](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%86_%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%83%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7), call him a sahabi (so you may find him as Busr al-Ashja'ii بسر الأشجعي in Usd al-Ghabah [أُسْد الغابة في معرفة الصحابة](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%BA%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A9_%D9%81%D9%8A_%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A9) of the historian [ibn al-Athyr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_ibn_al-Athir)) without quoting any hadith narrated on his authority, while others like al-Qadi 'Iyad said he is a munafiq (hypocrite).

The hadith was also compiled by ad-Darimi in his [Sunan](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=8&bookhad=2032), Imam Ahmad in his [Musnad](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=6&bookhad=16064), at-Tabarni in his [Kabir](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=84&bookhad=6188) and al-Bayhaqi in his [as-Sunan al-Kubra](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=71&bookhad=14154). All of them with the same first 3 narrators of sahih Muslim until: ... From 'Ikrmiah ibn 'Ammar عِكْرِمَة بْنِ عَمَّار from Iyyas ibn Salamah al-Akwa' إِيَاس بْنُ سَلَمَةَ بْنِ الأَكْوَع from his father Salamah ibn 'Amr al-Akwa' سَلَمَة بن عمرو بن الأَكْوَع (who witnessed what happened).

Comment: Is it ahad or motawatir?

Comment: @Kilise it would be at least mashhour

Answer (score 5):

It's an authentic hadith from Sahih Muslim.

It can be found here: https://sunnah.com/muslim/36/142